# Python csv file row by row, without using panda

Tags: python, csv

I would like to know if it is possible how to write a python script that reads an iris.csv file row by row, so that at any time only one row of data is in memory WITHOUT using panda?

I am aware how to do it with panda but not without it..

Comment: Check the built in csv module

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('myfile.csv') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        foo()
```